# How to i extrude 4 faces at the same time

Tags: mesh

[image]

I want to extrude them all to the center but i don't know how to do it, any recomendation¡?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To extrude all the selected faces to a central point you can simply press <kbd>E</kbd> to extrude but then cancel the extrusion with <kbd>Esc</kbd>. This will leave the newly extruded geometry in the same place as the originating faces, but still selected. Then simply scale them to 0 with <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>.

The above actions will scale the etruded faces to a *point* - ie, it will taper together at the central point. To avoid this you can apply the scale in all but one direction - in your case the 'depth' of the object is in the Y direction so you could use <kbd>S</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd> <kbd>0</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>.

[image: result]

Note that once you have scaled the faces together you might want to Remove Doubles to merge the vertices together.